# T <: A, return T method

Tags: scala, generics

here is some sample code:

```
trait A
trait B extends A

def test[T <: A](): T = {
  new B {}
}
```

but I get an compile error:

```
type mismatch;
found   : B
required: T
new B {}
```

how to make it working ?
( but without doing asInstanceOf[T] at the end )
thanks!

Comment: And what if I do `trait C extends A` and then I call `test[C]` _(which is correct)_ and then it returns a **B** but I wanted a **C**?! - What is the meta-problem you want to solve; Since this looks like an xy-problem.

Answer (score 6):

The signature of your method

```
def test[T <: A](): T
```

promises that **for any type** `T` that is a subtype of `A` you return a value of this type `T`. And then you returned a value of type `B`. You violated the signature (there are many subtypes of `A`, not only `B`).

For example you can try a type class (in this way you say that you return a value of `T` not for any `T <: A` at all but for any `T <: A` that can be handled by the type class `MakeT`)

```
def test[T <: A]()(implicit makeT: MakeT[T]): T = makeT.makeT()

trait MakeT[T] { // or MakeT[+T]
  def makeT(): T
}

object MakeT {
  implicit val bMakeT: MakeT[B] = () => new B {}
  // or implicit def bMakeT[T >: B]: MakeT[T] = () => new B {}
}

test[B]().isInstanceOf[B] // true
```

In the situation described by **@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez** in his comment

```
trait C extends A
```

you'll have

```
// test[C]() // doesn't compile, could not find implicit value for parameter makeT: MakeT[C]
```

Regarding generic return type see also

[Why can't I return a concrete subtype of A if a generic subtype of A is declared as return parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668592/why-cant-i-return-a-concrete-subtype-of-a-if-a-generic-subtype-of-a-is-declared/)

[Type mismatch on abstract type used in pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479695/type-mismatch-on-abstract-type-used-in-pattern-matching)

Or you can use standard type classes [`=:=`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/typeConstraints.scala#L205), [`<:<`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/typeConstraints.scala#L63)

```
def test[T <: A]()(implicit ev: B =:= T): T = {
  new B {}
}
```

([not `implicit ev: T =:= B`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849306/why-this-scala-code-has-a-compilation-error-type-mismatch))

or

```
def test[T <: A]()(implicit ev: B <:< T): T = {
  new B {}
}
```