# Proving that a match type resolves to a specific concrete type

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-3, match-types

I am trying to create an implementation of a trait that uses a match type, where the right-hand-side of that match type is known in advance. However, I can't seem to get the compiler to accept my "proof" of this. This is pretty new to me, so sorry if this is really obvious. Can someone help me understand if/how I can achieve what I want?

Here's some minimal code ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Q22I0DgkQO2KTJp9o5qSZw)) to illustrate what I'm doing:

```scala
class NumberBox {}

class LongBox {}

trait Boxer[T] {
  def box(): Boxer.Box[T]
}

object Boxer {
  type Box[T] = T match
    case Long => LongBox
    case _ => NumberBox
}

case class Val[T](v: T) extends Boxer[T] {
  def box(): Boxer.Box[T] = v match
    case _: Long => new LongBox()
    case _ => new NumberBox()
}

// here we prove that Boxer.Box[T] is a NumberBox
case class NoLongs[T](v: Boxer[T])(using Boxer.Box[T] =:= NumberBox) extends Boxer[T] {
  override def box(): Boxer.Box[T] = new NumberBox()
}

NoLongs(Val(1))
```

But this fails with:

```
Found:    NumberBox
Required: Boxer.Box[T]

Note: a match type could not be fully reduced:

  trying to reduce  Boxer.Box[T]
  failed since selector  T
  does not match  case Long => LongBox
  and cannot be shown to be disjoint from it either.
  Therefore, reduction cannot advance to the remaining case

    case _ => NumberBox
    override def box(): Boxer.Box[T] = new NumberBox()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala doesn't automatically apply proofs in the way you're looking for. But you're right that you do have a proof. In fact, your proof constitutes a callable object: the type [`=:=[From, To]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/=:=.html) defines a method called `apply`:

> ```
> override def apply(f: From): To
> ```

Now, you have a value of type `Boxer.Box[T] =:= NumberBox`, which means that `apply` would convert a `Boxer.Box[T]` to a `NumberBox`. You want the opposite: to convert a `NumberBox` into a `Boxer.Box[T]`. So we need to [`flip`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/=:=.html#flip-0) your proof around and then `apply` it.

> ```
> def flip: To =:= From
> ```

In your specific use case, consider

```
case class NoLongs[T](v: Boxer[T])(using eq: Boxer.Box[T] =:= NumberBox) extends Boxer[T] {
  override def box(): Boxer.Box[T] = eq.flip(new NumberBox())
}
```

We give the proof argument a name, `eq`, and then we apply its symmetric proof (that `NumberBox =:= Boxer.Box[T]`) to our `NumberBox` to convert it to the desired type.

You could also just take a proof that `NumberBox =:= Boxer.Box[T]` directly and get rid of the `flip`, if desired.

```
case class NoLongs[T](v: Boxer[T])(using eq: NumberBox =:= Boxer.Box[T]) extends Boxer[T] {
  override def box(): Boxer.Box[T] = eq(new NumberBox())
}
```

Comment: This was so helpful, thank you. I had no idea that =:= was callable like that 

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add to @SilvioMayolo's answer that

- type class `=:=` is not symmetric (i.e. if there is implicit `A =:= B` then generally there is no implicit `B =:= A` generated by compiler automatically)

[Why this scala code has a compilation error type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849306/why-this-scala-code-has-a-compilation-error-type-mismatch)

[T <: A, return T method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209514/t-a-return-t-method)

https://typelevel.org/blog/2014/07/02/type_equality_to_leibniz.html

https://typelevel.org/blog/2014/09/20/higher_leibniz.html

[In scala 3, is it possible to make covariant/contravariant type constructor to honour coercive subtyping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75762318/in-scala-3-is-it-possible-to-make-covariant-contravariant-type-constructor-to-h)

- you don't have to call `eq` explicitly

```
case class NoLongs[T](v: Boxer[T])(using NumberBox =:= Boxer.Box[T]) extends Boxer[T] {
  override def box(): Boxer.Box[T] = new NumberBox()
}
```

```
case class NoLongs[T](v: Boxer[T])(using eq: Boxer.Box[T] =:= NumberBox) extends Boxer[T] {
  given (NumberBox =:= Boxer.Box[T]) = eq.flip
  override def box(): Boxer.Box[T] = new NumberBox()
}
```

- you can have constraints in both directions

```
case class NoLongs[T](v: Boxer[T])(using Boxer.Box[T] =:= NumberBox, NumberBox =:= Boxer.Box[T]) extends Boxer[T] {
  override def box(): Boxer.Box[T] = new NumberBox()
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first bullet point (isn't `flip` quite literally a proof of the symmetric property, namely that `A =:= B` implies the existence of `B =:= A`?). But that is really interesting to know that Scala will use `=:=` constraints automatically if the `given` is in the right order. Is that a new feature in Scala 3 or did I just never notice it before?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo *"isn't `flip` quite literally a proof of the symmetric property"* It is but it's not an implicit. If there is implicit `A =:= B` then generally there is no implicit `B =:= A` generated by compiler automatically. *"Is that a new feature in Scala 3"* It exists in 2.x too. `A =:= B` extends `A => B`, so it defines an implicit conversion.